# Any generic type in C++ class

Tags: c++, templates, types, wildcard

Is there a way in C++ to specify any type* as type of a template, for example through a wildcard or some keyword.

I remember in Java we can do that using the ? wildcard as generic type, like  `HashMap<Long, ?>`.

I try to better explain the question using a sample code. Suppose we have the following Record class:

```
template<typename T>
class Record
{
    private:
        T content;
        long size;

    public:
        Record(T _content, long _size)
        {
            this->content = _content;
            this->size = _size;
        }

        T getContent()
        {
            return this->content;
        }

        long getSize()
        {
            return this->size;
        }
};
```

and suppose we want to use instances of the above class without specifying the exact type (I used the ? in the following class), simply because useless in the case in which the class Computer uses only the method `Record::getSize()`:

```
class Computer
{
    public:
        long long computeTotalSize(vector<Record<?>> recordVector)
        {
            long long totalSize = 0;
            for (vector<Record<?>>::iterator it = recordVector.begin() ; it != recordVector.end(); ++it)
                totalSize += (*it).getSize();

            return totalSize;
        }
};
```

Comment: If nothing but `size()` is used, why not pass a vector of sizes? Why pass a vector of `Record`? Anyway you can always use some minimal dummy type such as `char`.

Comment: You can make the function work with any record type the same way you made Record work with any type.

Comment: And as @Kevin says, you can just make `computeTotalSize` a template if you want to handle different `Record` types. An alternative is to derive `Record<T>` from an interface that declares a virtual `size()` function. But then the vector passed would have to be a vector of (possibly smart) pointers.

Comment: Side note: Double check your `Record` constructor. Use [member initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) to set the field values. And you should probably use `Record(const T &_content, long _size)` (plus a move version if appropriate). C++ isn't Java, currently (eventual copy elision aside) `_content` is copied twice.

Comment: Side note 2: the `get` prefixes are useful in Java, because Java has introspection, but they are of negative value in C++: just useless verbosity.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: About `get` and Java... I would say it's more of a convention. I've had to use Java frameworks which used reflection to automatically retrieve getters using nothing but naming conventions, and it was always a truly terrible experience, resulting in the most devious bugs one could imagine. Generally, one of the guidelines for robust Java is to avoid reflection entirely in all production code, but `get` and `set` prefixes are still so omnipresent in the Java world that IMO method names look strange without them, regardless of whether reflection is used or not.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: P.S.: Of course, I agree about not using them in C++.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make `computeTotalSize` a template function with the record template parameter as it's template parameter:

```
template <typename T>
long long computeTotalSize(vector<Record<T>> recordVector)
{
    long long totalSize = 0;
    for (vector<Record<T>>::iterator it = recordVector.begin() ; it != recordVector.end(); ++it)
        totalSize += (*it).getSize();

        return totalSize;
}
```

Note that you should also pass the vector by reference to avoid copying the entire thing:

```
long long computeTotalSize(const vector<Record<T>>& recordVector)
```

Answer (score 7):

It cannot be done the same way as in Java, because C++ templates are fundamentally different from Java generics (C++ templates generate entirely distinct types, not fancy constructs on top a type-erased type). However, you could make `computeTotalSize` a function template:

```
class Computer
{
    public:
        template <class T>
        long long computeTotalSize(const vector<Record<T>>& recordVector)
        {
            long long totalSize = 0;
            for (auto it = recordVector.begin() ; it != recordVector.end(); ++it)
                totalSize += it->getSize();

            return totalSize;
        }
};
```

Notice I took the liberty of streamlining the syntax of the code somewhat; the only behaviour change is using `const&` to pass the vector, to prevent copying it.

Note that the change to `const&` requires `getSize()` to be marked as a `const` member function:

```
long getSize() const
{
    return size;
}
```

Since it would be highly unexpected for a function called `getSize()` to modify the object on which it's called, this is actually a good thing.